# Prettier and ESLint + Airbnb quotes problem

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, single-quotes, eslint-config-airbnb

i've installed Prettier and ESLint with the airbnb styleguide in a react proyect and I can't get that when I press save the quotes stay simples

my .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb/hooks", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier":["error", {"endOfLine": "auto"}],
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
      "no-unused-vars": "warn",
      "func-names": "off",
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
      "eslint quotes": ["error", "single"],
      "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
      "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"]
  }
}
```

and my .prettierrc

```
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false
}
```

I've tried putting in both files the single quote option but still saving with doble

I get the lint error

> Replace `'container'` with `"container"`

And the prettier output is:

```
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Formatting c:\Users\toto\workspace\React\dumbapp\src\asd.js
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Using config file at 'c:\Users\toto\workspace\React\dumbapp\.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\Users\toto\workspace\React\dumbapp\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 12:23:38] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "babel"
}
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "c:\\Users\\toto\\workspace\\React\\dumbapp\\src\\asd.js",
  "parser": "babel",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2
}
["INFO" - 12:23:38] Formatting completed in 9.527ms.
```

Goal: Linting with airbnb style and formatting with prettier.

Comment: You didn't show a sample of the code you're trying to format. Is it JSX? Prettier has a separate option for quotes in JSX attributes.

Comment: It's a basic create-react-app, i'm just trying to get the right config for the airbnb-prettier

Comment: So is your question about JSX attributes or string literals?

Comment: Neither, I think... I only want the single quotes to remain in the on save with the prettier, in the JSX attributes and in the whole code

Comment: So is it "neither" or JSX after all? For JSX, you can add [`jsxSingleQuote: true`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-quotes) to `.prettierrc`, but note that the dominant convention is to use double quotes in JSX.